Bitcoinsground freeze my account when i asked for withdrawal?
"Hi everyone, I’m having a serious issue with the Bitcoinsground platform. They have frozen my account and are not allowing me to withdraw my funds. They’re asking me to double my funds before they will unfreeze my withdrawals. Has anyone else experienced this? Any advice on what steps I should take to resolve this? Thanks in advance for your help!"

Also see How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam
